# Как получить размер EditText?

Tags: java, android, android-edittext

Необходимо получить размер текста в `EditText` в dp, чтобы потом его изменить тоже в dp. Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Сначала получаем размер текста в `EditText` в `px`:

```
float textSizeInPx = mEditText.getTextSize();
```

Затем конвертируем `px` в `dp`:

```
int textSizeInDp = pxToDp((int) textSizeInPx);
```

Изменяем размер текста:

```
int newTextSizeInDp = textSizeInDp + 10;
```

И устанавливаем его для `EditText`:

```
mEditText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, newTextSizeInDp);
```

Для перевода `px` в `dp` использовался метод:

```
public static int pxToDp(int px) {
    return (int) (px / Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().density);
}
```

PS. Рекомендуемой единицей для размера шрифтов является `sp` (*scale-independent pixel*).

Answer (score 1):

На примере с `SeekBar`:

```
SeekBar seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekbar);
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.edittext);

    seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                editText.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP, progress);
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
```

Если нужно в SP то где `COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP` `DIP` меняете на `SP`.